# Elasticsearch, index first and last letter only, 'abc' => 'a' 'c'

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, analyzer

I'd like to index first and last letter only.

Eg.

'abc' would be indexed as 'a' and 'c'

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern analyzer would be an option. Example:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "firstAndLast": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "(?<=^.).*(?=.$)" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This pattern would produce the following tokens from the following inputs:

`abc` => `a` `c`

`abc def` => `a` `f`

EDIT:
If you would like to produce first and last for every word you have to define a custom analyzer as follows:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "regexpFilter": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": "false",
          "patterns": [
            "(^\w)|(\w$)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "test": {
          "filter": [
            "regexpFilter"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I always used `whitespace` as a tokenizer, can this be used as a filter as well? (I think analyzer applies tokenizer then filter), oh nvm, so I could use [whitespace, firstandLast] tokenizer right?

Comment: It seems, there is a pattern replace filter. And maybe we can replace other letters (except first and last) to empty string? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html  Although I have no idea how I should construct the regex..

Comment: I explain that part wrongly. If you would like to produce first and last letter from every word (not every string as I answered). You should create a custom analyzer. Defining, for example, a replace token filter for removing all letters except first and last letters and a whitespace tokenizer. But just an idea it depends on your use case. I have to test it

Comment: `"first_last": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "(?<=^.).*(?=.$)",
                    "replacement": "(1) (2)"
                }`, Don't you think something like this should work? I apply ['whitespace', 'first_last', 'whitespace'] as a filter

Comment: Just edited the answer with a custom analyzer that should work. Pattern replace doesn't work because it only produce one token for each word and we should produce two tokens (first and last letter) for every word. For that reason I ended up using `pattern_capture`

Comment: oh.. so pattern_capture can produce multiple tokens? I found 'pattern_repace' and 'ngram' (with 1gram) works as well.